# C# .net 6 routing: generic solution to get a parameter from query or path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I am trying to find a solution to get a parameter (username) from a GET request.
This parameter can be sent either by query or in the path (both method are valid).
Valid examples:

```
GET /users/my_name

GET /users?login=my_name
```

Using .NET 6 I found a solution to get this parameter from path:

```
[HttpGet("{login?}")]
public IActionResult Get(string login)
{
  if (login == null)
    return GetAllusers();
  return GetUserByLogin(login);
}
```

or to get this parameter from query:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(string login)
{
  if (login == null)
    return GetAllusers();
  return GetUserByLogin(login);
}
```

But I have no solution that will fill the login parameter in both cases.
Is there a generic solution where I could have this parameter filled in both cases?

I found a workaround that is given bellow but I am not sure this is the best way to handle this problem:

```
[HttpGet("{login_path?}")]
public IActionResult Get(string login_path, string login)
{
  string user = (login_path != null) ? login_path : login;

  if (user == null)
    return GetAllusers();
  return GetUserByLogin(user);
}
```

Comment: You want anonymous login.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @jdweng Nope, absolutely not

Comment: You have two different requests 1) With parameter Login 2) Without parameter login.  So the second can be handled with a default option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When path parameter is null read the value from query string using `HttpContext.Request.Query`.

```
[HttpGet("{login?}")]
public IActionResult Get(string login)
{
    login ??= HttpContext.Request.Query["login"];
        
    if (login == null)
        return GetAllusers();
    return GetUserByLogin(login);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to combine the methods mentioned in a custom attribute!?